# When Renaming table name, it is actually dropping table from Mysql - Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, table-rename

I am running into a very weird problem in my PHP script when trying to rename my table name. Instead of renaming it, it is dropping it.

**Background Info:**

1. I am running the script on my browser
2. Rename to the original table name happens right after the drop of original table.

**Code Example:**

```
$tableSuffix = "1";
$tableSuffix2 = "2";

// This table already exists "testing_$tableSuffix LIKE template_testing"

// This is being created
CREATE TABLE testing_$tableSuffix2 LIKE template_testing

$queryString = "DROP TABLE testing_$tableSuffix";
$query = $db->query($queryString);
    
$queryString = "RENAME TABLE testing_$tableSuffix2 TO testing_$tableSuffix";
$query = $db->query($queryString);
```

Renaming is not happening and both `testing_$tableSuffix` and `testing_$tableSuffix2` are dropping and getting deleted.

Comment: If you ran the script twice you'd see exactly that. No tables and the second rename would fail.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that I am creating the table as well in another function before this. Let me update my description.

Comment: If you just want to efficiently get rid of all the data in a table just do `TRUNCATE TABLE some_table;`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured out the bug. Not sure yet though why it is happening on Chrome only and not Safari. My script is running 2 instances within 2 seconds on Chrome, however this issue does not happen on Safari.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).